# ng-select doesn't work on rendering array list?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Don't know what's wrong, any clue guys? I found it's not nice to use ng-repeat, tried ng-select but doesn't render anything.

```
<select name="country" ng-model="user.country"
                  ng-options="country.name for country in country_list" >
              {{name}}
          </select>

$sope.country_list = [
      {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'}, 
      {name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'}, 
      {name: 'Albania', code: 'AL'}, 
      {name: 'Algeria', code: 'DZ'}, 
      {name: 'American Samoa', code: 'AS'}, 
      {name: 'AndorrA', code: 'AD'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo line 6,  $scope not $sope

Comment: ah I see lol. WHy the first option is blank? how to set default value?

Comment: you need to set the ng-model of the select to the first object in the array
https://jsfiddle.net/tef7wwxu/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
<select ng-options="country as country.name for country in country_list" ></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo `$scope` not `$sope`. See working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vincentluth/9ehj8gde/)